# Convert date format to 'YYYY-MM-DD' in DateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

```
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);
```

```
function get_range(){
     var ts_cd = $('#reportrange span').text();
     var sep_date = ts_cd.split("-");
     console.log(sep_date);
     return sep_date;
}
```

Here I am getting date as like this `January 25 2018`.  I need it in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
This is a `date Range Picker`, so, Please help me regarding that

Comment: Convert it after selection with Moment, i have found trying to do it on the fly can be tricky with different datetime plugins, some work, some dont, its easier to do the convert after selection.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   
    <div>
        Date: <input type="text" id="tbDate" />
    </div>
</body>
            
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id$=tbDate]').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'yy-MM-dd'
        
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited

```
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
```